# How to continue the while loop after outputting the statement twice?

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement

I could loop the switch statement only twice. After the second time the console closes no matter what option I have chosen from the switch case. How I should modify my code so that the user could continue to loop the switch case until they decide to stop?

Thank you for your suggestions.

```
int userChoice = 0;

Console.WriteLine("This is an application. It has many different modes.");
Console.WriteLine("You can activate the mode of the application, which can be inserting, retrieving, printing, saving or uploading.");
Console.WriteLine("Type 'I' to insert, 'R' to retrieve, 'P' to print, 'S' to save, 'U' to upload the data, or 'T' to terminate the application.");

string mode = Console.ReadLine();

switch (mode)
{
    case "I":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to insert the data.");
        break;                        

    case "R":
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to retrieve the data.");
            break;

    case "P":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to print the data.");
        break;

    case "S":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to save the data.");
        break;

    case "U":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to upload the data.");
        break;

    case "T":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to terminate the application.");                      
        return;                        
}

// Two modes, quit option
if (mode == "I" || mode == "R")
{
    Console.WriteLine("The application will stay in the insert or retrieve modes. Press 'Q' to exit to the modes to return to the main menu.");
}   

while (userChoice != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose one of the modes {0}.", userChoice);                
            userChoice++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Type 'I' to insert, 'R' to retrieve, 'P' to print, 'S' to save, 'U' to upload the data, or 'T' to terminate the application.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You need to put the code you want executed *inside* the loop

Comment: Your switch statement isn't contained in any loop

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like this (pseudocode)

```
bool finished
while(!finished) //Loop until they make a choice
{
   Console.WriteLine("Type 'I' to insert, 'R' to retrieve, 'P' to print, 'S' to save, 'U' to upload the data, or 'T' to terminate the application.");
   var input = Console.Readline();
   switch(input)
   {
      //Respond to the input. If the input should cause the application
      //to terminate, set finished = true
   }

   if(!finished)
   {
       //Indicate that the user can make more choices
   }
}

// The loop exits when finished = true, and the program ends
```

Comment: I have put my code inside the while loop and it worked. However, I have used int type instead of bool. Thank you very much.